# Celery Flower is Not Using Broker Settings in flowerconfig.py

Tags: rabbitmq, celery, flower

I'm using Flower to monitor my Celery task queues. I have the following settings in my **flowerconfig.py**:

```html
###################
# Celery Settings #
###################
BROKER_URL = 'amqp://<REDACTED>:<REDACTED>@localhost:5672/some_app'
```

When I start flower from within the folder containg **flowerconfig.py**, however, it appears to be connecting to the default virtualhost using the guest credentials:

```
[celery@<REDACTED> bin]$ flower
[I 151006 16:02:30 command:113] Visit me at http://127.0.0.1:5555
[I 151006 16:02:30 command:115] Broker: amqp://guest:**@localhost:5672//
[I 151006 16:02:30 command:118] Registered tasks:
    ['celery.backend_cleanup',
     'celery.chain',
     'celery.chord',
     'celery.chord_unlock',
     'celery.chunks',
     'celery.group',
     'celery.map',
     'celery.starmap']
[I 151006 16:02:30 mixins:225] Connected to amqp://guest:**@127.0.0.1:5672//
```

If I pass the argument via CLI, it work correctly though.
I've straced the command and it appears to open the file RO without issue. 
I've also confirmed other settings in that file are applied successfully.

I'm currently using Celery v0.8.3.

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong? Or is this a bug that I should report?

Comment: Try to replace BROKER_URL with broker

Comment: Thank you! I'll give this a try in a few minutes and get back to you.

Comment: @PaulCalabro: so did it work?

Comment: I have been struggling with the same issue as mentioned in this question. And tried what was suggested in the comments to replace BROKER_URL with BROKER & it still does not work. Flower still picks up the default broker settings from the celery config. Also, I stumbled upon this: https://github.com/mher/flower/issues/544 which seems to suggest why this doesn't work.